# App crashing when loading NIBs - but only after firmware upgrade to iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, ios5, nib

Some users of my app have reported crashes occurring only when opening the app after a firmware upgrade to iOS 5. Everything was fine prior to the firmware upgrade - including running the app and upgrading to a newer version of the app and then running it.

The crash log indicates the crash is occurring when a NIB is loaded:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x32bb38bf __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36a1d1e5 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32bb37b9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32bb37db +[NSException raise:format:] + 35
4   UIKit                           0x3169a747 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1567
5   UIKit                           0x3160a9cb -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 247
6   UIKit                           0x314e9ea1 -[UIViewController loadView] + 89
7   UIKit                           0x3145f78b -[UIViewController view] + 51
8   UIKit                           0x3146bc39 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 25
9   UIKit                           0x3146baa9 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 37
10  UIKit                           0x3146b98f -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 35
11  UIKit                           0x3146b211 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 501
12  UIKit                           0x3146af53 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 251
13  UIKit                           0x3145f673 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 807
14  UIKit                           0x3145f349 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 37
```

For some reason, deleting and reinstalling the app *after* the iOS 5 firmware upgrade seems to resolve the issue.

I'm utterly baffled as to what the cause could be. I'd really appreciate any thoughts you may have.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Apple changed how they de-serialize NIBs. I had changed to shipping with uncompiled NIBs instead of shipping with compiled NIBs. Compiling NIBs again fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've observed this behavior in many apps. My best guess is that it's trying to load previous interface state through a serialized bundle as the argument of -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:], but that the bundle class has someone changed how it serializes between 4 and 5.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I just wish there was something I could do :)